# Port forwarding failure on a Zyxel VMG8324-B10A

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I’m trying to port forward a [TeamSpeak 3](http://www.teamspeak.com) server, I’ve done this several times before with success. But now I have a new router and it doesn't seem like it wants to play nice. I confirmed that the server is in working order by connecting to it through the local IP Address in advance, for double checking. I can connect through the local IP address, but not the external IP address.

The router model is a [Zyxel VMG8324-B10A](http://www.zyxel.com/us/en/products_services/vmg8324_b10a.shtml?t=p)

The ports are:

- 9987 (UDP)
- 10011 (TCP)
- 30033 (TCP)

Note that the first port is the only one that truly matters for connecting to the server.

Local IP Address of the server computer is `192.168.1.39`

[This is what my attempt looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GBPB.jpg) (Image)

And I did confirm that VDSL is the active WAN Interface used for my internet connection. There’s also IPTV-VDSL in use for Internet TV; other interfaces show no activity.

The one thing I myself notice that I find confusing is that I need to enter two IP addresses, in an older Zyxel router model I once had this wasn’t the case—but I tried various combinations without success—I also tried disabling the firewall in the router, I still couldn't connect to the server. The server’s firewall is correctly configured, it was working just fine in it’s current state on a different router.

What am I doing wrong?

Update: I wasn't doing anything wrong, and the router was not broken either, I will be trying another router soon, and if I run into the same issue, it's an ISP issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had issues with this also but for me making one for each WAN Interface worked. So in total you will have 9 instead of 3. Just make 3 of the exact same rules but change the WAN Interface on each one. You should only have 3 WAN Interface options.

Answer (score 2):

I called my ISP, in this case the WAN IP field was ok to leave empty according to them. They grubbed around a bit and in the end said that the router I was using had to be faulty and we have to exchange it.

We're going to do that, I'll update this answer if it'll work with another router of the same model.

Update: I got a new router of the same model, the same problem occurred again, my ISP's customer support had no clue why. I will try again with another router, it may actually be an ISP issue.

Update2: It worked with another router, I believe this was an ISP issue however, I was living in a relatively remote town, I have no idea what may have caused this, but people living in a more central area with the same ISP and router were not running into this problem. If I recall correctly my friend who lived in the same area also switched to this ISP and experienced the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have the vmg8324-b10a and port forwarding works just fine. Make sure you have a recent firmware, V7 or V8, available from https://www.tweak.nl/support/firmware.html

The WAN IP address should be blank as your IP has suggested, otherwise the rules appear fine.
You must be using VDSL for internet, rather than ADSL or Ethernet, as you have the rules configured on the VDSL interface.
The rules are active when the status light is yellow, as yours appear to be. A port will not appear open on the WAN *unless* there is a service, on your LAN, listening on that port. You can test if they are open by using netcat, or equivalent, to listen on each port and use a port scanner to scan your WAN interface, public, IP address.

Answer (score -1):

The WAN ip should be your public facing IP address (see http://www.whatismyip.com)

There could be a few other things such as being behind a second router or CGN, but, try the above first and then we can move on to other issues...

Comment: I tried this, the ports remain closed. I am not behind a second router to my knowledge, this router is connected directly to the wall/modem output.

Comment: Your WAN ip is not the same as the LAN ip and that is why it is not working - or/and, your ISP is using CGN or port blocking.

Comment: I guess I can't rule out a CGN; but it seems very unlikely.

I did notice one strange behavior, wich was that I could use SSH through the public IP address on a computer connected to the same network (on port 22 which seemed to be forwarded by default) but from another network the attempt to connect gets a timeout.